# If the limit of a function at infty is equal to its value in some point then it has an inflection point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:[a,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be two times differentiable.
>
> If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=f(a)$ then there exists $x\in [a,\infty)$ such that $$f^"(x)=0.$$

I tried to show that it is, for example, convex and get contradiction, however I got nowhere.

Any comment?

Comment: In the post only the differentiability and limit facts assumed, but in title one more assumption the function takes same value (at least) twice. Do you mean to include this last assumption? If so put in body of post, if not change title.

Comment: Your title is wrong. For instance, $f(x)=x(1-x)$ takes equal values at $0$ and $1$, but it has no point of inflection. (The body of the post is, however, correct.)

Comment: Try applying the Mean Value Theorem. (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)=f'(c). L.H.S is zero, so f'(c)=0 which means there is an inflection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Since any derivative has IVP it follows that $f''(x) >0$ for all $x$ or $f''(x) <0$ for all $x$. The second case can be reduced to the first by changing $f$ to $-f$ so assume that $f''(x) >0$ for all $x$. This means $f$ is  convex. Let $a <b <\infty$. Convexity implies that $f(x) \geq f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)$ for all $x$. If $f'(b) >0$ this leads to the contradiction that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence $f'(b) \leq 0$ for all $x$. Thus $f$ is decreasing. This, together with the hypothesis that $f(x) \to f(a)$ as $x \to \infty$ implies that $f$ is a constant and $f''(x)\equiv 0$!

Answer (score 1):

**Higlights** - Try to fill in details:

Assume $\;f\;$ isn't constant (otherwise the claim is trivially true), then $\;f\;$ must either decrease from $\;a\;$ and then increase towards $\;f(a)\;$ when $\;x\to\infty\;$ , or increase from $\;a\;$ and decrease towards $\;f(a)\;$ when $\;x\to\infty\;$ . It doesn't matter whether $\;f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}f(a)\;$ from above, from below or from both sides afinire or infinite number of times, what matters is that $\;f\;$ increases and decreases (or the other way around) within tis domain.

The above means that $\;f'(x)\;$ changes sign from $\;-\;$ to $\;+\;$ or the other way around at least once, and since $\;f'(x)\;$ is continuous (why?), this means it must have at least a maximum or minimum point somewhere. Finish now the argument (further hint: what happens with $\;\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)\;\ldots\;$? You may want to use MVT)

Comment: I think your first sentence is false. $x^4\sin\frac{1}{x}$ or something.

Comment: @TonyK Perhaps "something", as $$x^4\sin\frac1x=x^3\frac{\sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$$ so your example doesn't fit the problem's conditions. Or perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: I was pointing out that your first sentence was false, by showing how a counter-example might behave for small $x$. You can multiply it by $e^{-x}$ if you need it spelling out.

Comment: @TonyK I need more than spelling out: I can't see your point yet. The function begins at $\;f(a)\;$ , and it comes  back to it *at the limit* when $\;x\to\infty\;$ . So it comes back from above, from below or asymptotically. Anyway, how is that sentence false?! In fact, I can't see how **a continuous** function can fail to be as I describe it according to the given data. Please develop your counter example.

Comment: Does $f$ in my counter-example increase from $0$ or decrease from $0$? Neither -- in any neighbourhood of $0$ it is both increasing and decreasing. I see what you are getting at, but you put it badly: all you need is some $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)\ne f(a)$, and then you can invoke the MVT on $(a,x_0)$ and $(x_0,\infty)$ (or rather, on $(x_0,M)$ for some suitably large $M$).

Comment: @TonyK  Who cares it is both increasing and decreasing in any neighborhood, a finite or an infinite number of times?! The point, as you surely can notice, is that it is **both** somewhere after the very first point at $\;a\;$ !! So your counter example not only that it doesn't counters anything I wrote, it also doesn't counter a function with the properties as required in the OP... And besides all this, the answer was "highlights", which is just another way to say: Hey, here are some hints for you. Fill up gaps" . BTW, the answer that was accepted uses the same line of logic...

Comment: It's just sloppy, if you ask me.

Comment: @tonyk Perhaps it is, but it is undoubtedly correct...and your counter example isn't, as the fact is that *with the given data*, the derivative function **must** have an extreme value somewhere in $\;(a,\infty)\;$, and thus precisely there the second derivative will vanish. This is exactly what is implied and hinted with my post.